# Formal charge and net charge

Tags: lewis-structure, formal-charge

What is the basic difference between formal charge and net charge . Does formal charge take part in resonance .

I searched it on wikipedia , but it is mostly discussing how to find formal charge.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_charge

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48189/difference-between-oxidation-and-formal-charge?s=4|2.7337 http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14478/the-definition-of-formal-charge?s=2|2.7995

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Net charge is the sum of all formal charges of the atoms in a molecule. Net charge is the charge of the molecule.

Formal charge is the charge of an atom in a molecule. Formal charge varies when you look at resonance structure. [See this post of the nitrate resonance structures](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9304/is-this-a-valid-structure-for-the-nitrate-ion/9305#9305). It can be obtained through:

\begin{equation}
Formal\ charge\ =\ Valence\ electrons\ -\ no\ bonding\ electrons\ -\ \frac{bonding\ electrons}{2}\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\text{(Eq. 1)}
\end{equation}

**Example**: I take the example given previously with $\ce{NO3^{-}}$, in order to give a complete answer to the present post.

So, Having in mind the rules to draw the Lewis Structure:

- **Operations**

  1. Sum the valence electrons of all atoms. *When the system is an anion, an electron is added. When the system is a cation, an electron is subtracted.*
  2. Sum the 'octet-electron duet' of all atoms.
  3. Subtract step 2 of 1. Results corresponds to shared or bonding electrons.
  4. Subtract step 3 of 1. Result corresponds to the nonbonding electrons.
- **Indications**

  1. Assigns two electrons to each bond.
  2. If electrons remain from step 3. Add them in pairs creating double or triple bonds. Having in mind the duplet/octet rule.
  3. The obtained electrons from step 4. Add them in pairs to the more electronegative atoms.
  4. Calculate the formal charge of each atom.

**Then:**

- **Operations**

  1. $$valence\ electrons\ \cdot\ number\ atoms\ of\ \ce{N}\ +\ valence\ electrons\ \cdot\ number\ of\ \ce{O}\ +\ anion\ condition $$ Then $$5\cdot 1+6\cdot 3+1=24$$
  2. $$octet\ of\ \ce{N}\ \cdot\ number\ atoms\ of\ \ce{N}\ +\ octet\ of\ \ce{O}\ \ \cdot\ number\ of\ \ce{O} $$ Then $$8\cdot 1+8\cdot 3=32$$
  3. $$32-24=8$$
  4. $$24-8=16$$

     - **Indications**

After doing the first three steps, you will get:

[image] (Source: [Stackexchange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ819.gif))

Now, taken equation 1 to nitrogen:

$$Formal\ charge\ of\ \ce{N} =\ 5\ -\ 0\ -\ \frac{8}{2}\ =\ +1$$

Now, taken equation 1 to oxygen bonded to nitrogen through single bond:

$$Formal\ charge\ of\ \ce{O} =\ 6\ -\ 6\ -\ \frac{2}{2}\ =\ -1$$

Now, taken equation 1 to oxygen bonded to nitrogen through double bond:

$$Formal\ charge\ of\ \ce{O} =\ 6\ -\ 4\ -\ \frac{4}{2}\ =\ 0$$

**Therefore**

Net charge of $\ce{NO3^-}$ is the sum of all formal charge of the atoms in the molecule equals to **-1**